# VBA string array with unknown amount of strings

Tags: arrays, string, vba, indexoutofboundsexception

First of all let me all congratulate you on a superb forum! it's helped me Loads! so far with getting my little program working... and now I'm finally stuck.

I am attempting to automate Outlook to send tailored Offers to clients through a UserForm.

We offer 5 types of solutions and I don't know if the client will want 1 (DCF) or 2 (Top-Slice) or 3 (Ertragswert) or 4 (Belwert) or the 5 (Sachwert) of them. So I need a way for the code to check how many Checkboxes are ticked and then order them into a string (I've named it ValTyp) and separate them with comas and insert an "and"before the last. Say client wants 1, 3 and 5. The solution would be DCF, Ertragswert and Sachwert. So far I have my checkboxes all checking for values as follows:

```
Public iSach As String
Private Sub CKSach_Click()

   Dim Sach As Boolean

   Sach = CKSach.Value

   If Sach = True Then
      iSach = "Sachwert "
      ValCount = ValCount + 1
   Else
      iSach = ""
      ValCount = ValCount - 1
   End If

End Sub
```

I have attempted at building an IF statement for a similar part which has 3 options and one is a must:

```
If (iRics <> "" And iBelSTD <> "" And iImmo <> "") Then
    Standard = (iRics & ", " & iBelSTD & "und " & iImmo)
ElseIf (iBelSTD <> "" Or iImmo <> "") Then
    Standard = (iRics & "und " & iImmo & iBelSTD)
Else
    Stadard = iRics
End If
```

I am thinking of creating an array, with the length of ValCount... but I seem to be completely unable t get it to work:

```
Dim Services() As String
ReDim Services(0 To 4) As String

If iDCF <> "" Then
   Services(0) = iDCF
End If
If iDCF <> "" Then
   Services(1) = iCore
End If
If iDCF <> "" Then
   Services(2) = iErtrag
End If
If iDCF <> "" Then
   Services(3) = iSach
End If
If iDCF <> "" Then
   Services(4) = iBelVT
End If

Debug.Print Services(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I get an runtime-error 9 index outside bounds.
I have no idea what to do and I haven't even got to how to include the commas and "and".

Any help at all will be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance! 
Cliff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach it like this: first, you store your checkboxes in a collection:

```
Dim cbs As New Collection
cbs.Add checkbox1
cbs.Add checkbox2
'...
cbs.Add checkbox5
```

Hence, you loop inside it to add the checked values into a new collection:

```
Dim myStr As String: myStr = ""
Dim cbsCheck As New Collection
'count "true"
For j = 1 To cbs.Count
    If cbs(j).Value = True Then
        cbsCheck.Add cbs(j)
    End If
Next j
'hence you compose the string
If cbsCheck.Count = 0 Then
    myStr = "No element selected"
ElseIf cbsCheck.Count = 1 Then
    myStr = "You selected " & cbsCheck(1).Caption
Else
    k = 1
    myStr = "You selected "
    While k < cbsCheck.Count 
        myStr = myStr & cbsCheck(k).Caption & ", "
        k = k + 1
    Loop
    myStr = myStr & "and " & cbsCheck(k+1).Caption
End If
```

**NOTE** when you want to compose an array of elements of which you do NOT know the size in advance, in 95% of cases the object `Collection` is better than an object `String Array`.

Comment: It worked super well! made also half of my code redundant... Which I guess is always good for the learning curve! 
I changed it a bit so that the second to last check did not add a coma by inserting an If statement in the loop:

    While k < cbsCheck.Count 
         If k = cbsCheck.Count - 1 Then
                myStr = myStr & cbsCheck(k).Caption
        Else
                myStr = myStr & cbsCheck(k).Caption & ", "
                k = k + 1
        End If
    Loop
        If k = cbsCheck.Count - 1 Then
        myStr = myStr & cbsCheck(k).Caption

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collection instead of an array, which is most of the cases the better solution. If you really need an array for some reason, you can use the [redim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx) function to resize an array:

Example:

```
Dim myArray(3) As String

    myArray(1) = "a"
    myArray(2) = "b"
    myArray(3) = "c"
    ReDim myArray(4) As String
    myArray(4) = "d"
```

You can also add a Preserve after ReDim to make sure the values won't get lost.